# Passing arguments between Gatling scenarios and simulation

Tags: scala, rest, gatling

I'm current creating some Gatling simulation to test a REST API. I don't really understand Scala.

I've created a scenario with several exec and pause;

```
object MyScenario { 

  val ccData = ssv("cardcode_fr.csv").random
  val nameData = ssv("name.csv").random
  val mobileData = ssv("mobile.csv").random
  val emailData = ssv("email.csv").random
  val itemData = ssv("item_fr.csv").random  

  val scn = scenario("My use case")
    .feed(ccData)
    .feed(nameData)
    .feed(mobileData)
    .feed(emailData)
    .feed(itemData)
    .exec(
      http("GetCustomer")
        .get("/rest/customers/${CardCode}")
        .headers(Headers.headers)
        .check(
          status.is(200)
        )
     )
     .pause(3, 5)
     .exec(
      http("GetOffers")
        .get("/rest/offers")
        .queryParam("customercode", "${CardCode}")
        .headers(Headers.headers)
        .check(
          status.is(200)
        )
      )
}
```

And I've a simple Simulation :

```
class MySimulation extends Simulation {
  setUp(MyScenario.scn
    .inject(
        constantUsersPerSec (1 ) during (1)))
    .protocols(EsbHttpProtocol.httpProtocol)
    .assertions(
      global.successfulRequests.percent.is(100))

}
```

The application I'm trying to simulate is a multilocation mobile App, so I've prepared a set of samples data for each Locale (US, FR, IT...)

My REST API handles all the locales, therefore I want to make the simulation concurrently execute several instances of **MyScenario**, each with a different locale sample, to simulate the global load.

Is it possible to execute my simulation without having to create/duplicate the scenario and change **the val ccData = ssv("cardcode_fr.csv").random** for each one?

Also, each locale has its own load, how can I create a simulation that takes a single scenario and executes it several times concurrently with a different load and feeders?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what you've said, I think this may be a good approach:

Start by grouping your data in such a way that you can look up each item you want to send based on the current locale.  For this, I would recommend using a Map that matches a locale string (such as "FR") to the item that matches that locale for the field you're looking to fill in.  Then, at the start of each iteration of the scenario, you just pick which locale you want to use for the current iteration from a list.  It would look something like this:

```
val locales = List("US", "FR", "IT")
val names = Map( "US" -> "John", "FR" -> "Pierre", "IT" -> "Guillame")

object MyScenario {
    //These two lines pick a random locale from your list
    val random_index = rand.nextInt(locales.length);
    val currentLocale = locales(random_index);
    //This line gets the name
    val name = names(currentLocale)
    //Do the rest of your logic here
}
```

This is a very simplified example - you'll have to figure out how you actually want to retrieve the data from files and put it into a Map structure, as I assume you don't want to hard code every item for every field into your code.

Comment: I don't think this answers the question. It provides a solution using random, but doesn't help pass parameters for the simulation to the scenario.

Comment: Well, for that, you just have to manually add the parameters, possibly with `.queryParam()` or (if you put multiple parameters into a sequence) `queryParamSeq()`